# Applying DataAnnotations (MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I consume an API that has a full object set. I don't want to have to re-create an object model in the mvc3 code just to use the DataAnnotations.

Is there a way to use this feature with out a wrapper class? The objects have their own validation rules that I can reuse, but want to use the built in mvc framework to display the messages back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class which inherits from `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`, where you can consume your object set, and write out the items as `DataAnnotations`.  A brief example:

```
public class MyModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    private MyEntities _db = new MyEntities();

    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(
        IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, 
        Type containerType, 
        Func<object> modelAccessor, 
        Type modelType, 
        string propertyName)
    {
        var modelMetadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        // load object
        var objectSet = _db.ObjectSets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyName == propertyName);

        // check attributes
        if (objectSet.IsRequired)
            modelMetadata.IsRequired = true;

        return modelMetadata;
    }
}
```

Then, register your provider in Global.asax.cs in the `Application_Start` method, as follows:

```
        ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MyModelMetadataProvider();
```

Comment: What is the overhead of doing the reflection?

Comment: @Amej65, it is not possible to say what the overhead will be without specifics.  If the object set is an assembly, then the reflection will be only a small percentage of the overhead in processing the request.  If the object set exists in a database, then the cost will be higher, due to the database calls. In your case, where the information comes from the API, it is a question of the overhead in getting the information from the API.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a metadata class as in the following example from [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs) link though I guess you'd have to add the MetaDataType attribute programatically...

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(MovieMetaData))]
    public partial class Movie
    {
    }


    public class MovieMetaData
    {
        [Required]
        public object Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(5)]
        public object Director { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("Date Released")]
        [Required]
        public object DateReleased { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never tried this. You can write a base class in MVC model that all API classes inherit. Implement IValidatableObject on that base class and use your existing validation rules. Using MetadataType, you will still have to rewrite the class with those fileds you need validation on.